# Joint PMF of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to understand if the following is correct:

$$P[X = x, \phi(X) = \phi(x)] = P[X=x]  \ \ \ \  (I)$$

Intuitively, it seems correct. I'm trying to prove this with the following:

$$ P[X = x, \phi(X) = \phi(x)] =  P[\phi(X) = \phi(x)| X=x]P[X=x] $$

We have $P[\phi(X) = \phi(x)| X=x] = 1$. This seems messy, there is a formal proof of equality (I)? Is this equality even correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The events $\{X=x\}$ and $\{X=x, \phi (X)=\phi (x)\}$ are one and the same. Verify that each side is a subset of the other.

Comment: can you explain more? thanks!

Comment: @Felipe Try to show 2 events $X=x$ and $(X=x,\phi(X)=\phi(x))$ are the same. Here is one direction: if $X=x$, then certainly both $X=x$ and $\phi(X)=\phi(x)$ are true.